# CUDA out of memory during loss.backward(), torch.bmm works fine while doing forward computation

Tags: python, deep-learning, pytorch

I wrote the following codes to do doc-level pair-wise attention.
`

```
def bi_linear_attn(self, Q, K):
    """
    :param Q: 1*b*d
    :param K: n*b*d
    :return:  (for relative part and irrelative part)
    """
    v = K.permute(1, 2, 0)
    # b*1*n && b*s*n
    # here!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
    interaction = torch.bmm(Q.permute(1, 0, 2), torch.bmm(
        self.bi_linear_para.unsqueeze(0).expand(v.shape[0], *self.bi_linear_para.shape), v))

    print(interaction.shape)
    direct_score = F.softmax(interaction, dim=2)
    print(direct_score.shape)
    inverse_score = 1 - direct_score
    h_dir = torch.bmm(direct_score, K.permute(1, 0, 2))
    h_inv = torch.bmm(inverse_score, K.permute(1, 0, 2))
    # b * 1 * d
    return h_dir, h_inv

def forward(self, bid2emb):
    blk_num = len(bid2emb)
    tuple_lst = sorted([(bid, emb_tuple[0], emb_tuple[1]) for bid, emb_tuple in bid2emb.items()])
    id_zip, h_zip, c_zip = zip(*tuple_lst)
    h_stack = torch.cat([h.repeat(1, blk_num, 1) for h in list(h_zip)], dim=1)
    # -- pad context
    c_lst_padded = []
    stc_len = [c.shape[0] for c in list(c_zip)]
    max_stc_len = max(stc_len)
    for c in list(c_zip):
        if c.shape[0] < max_stc_len:
            c_pad = F.pad(c, (0, 0, 0, 0, 0, max_stc_len - c.shape[0]), 'constant', 0.)
        else:
            c_pad = c
        c_lst_padded.append(c_pad)
    c_stack = torch.cat(c_lst_padded * blk_num, dim=1)
    h_dir, h_inv = self.bi_linear_attn(h_stack, c_stack)
    # -- get ind
    AB_lst, BA_lst = [], []
    for bid_A, emb_tuple_A in bid2emb.items():
        for bid_B, emb_tuple_B in bid2emb.items():
            if bid_A == bid_B:
                continue
            AB_lst.append(bid_A * blk_num + bid_B)
            BA_lst.append(bid_B * blk_num + bid_A)
    AB_idx = torch.tensor(AB_lst).to(device)
    BA_idx = torch.tensor(BA_lst).to(device)
    # n * 1 * d
    h_dir = torch.mean(
        torch.cat((torch.index_select(h_dir, 0, AB_idx), torch.index_select(h_dir, 0, BA_idx)), dim=1), dim=1,
        keepdim=True)
    h_inv = torch.mean(
        torch.cat((torch.index_select(h_inv, 0, AB_idx), torch.index_select(h_inv, 0, BA_idx)), dim=1), dim=1,
        keepdim=True)
    print('hdir', h_dir.shape)
    return torch.cat((h_dir, h_inv), dim=2)`
```

In line 10, I tried to compute interaction score with `x1 A x2`, where x1 and x2 has the shape of 36000*1*512 and 36000*max_len*512.  Due to the large batch size, the matmul failed due to memory error, after changing matmul to bmm with expanded parameter matric, the forward computation works fine. However the memory error appears when doing backpropagation. Which is confusing to me.

I would really appreciate any help on this as I am completely perplexed